# How to pipe output of program as it runs into xxd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to be able to see the output of my program in hex, as it runs, however if I pipe the output into xxd it will only print once the program has stopped running.

These are the things that that I've tried:

```sh
./a.out | while read LINE; do echo "$LINE" | xxd; done

./a.out | xxd
```

This is what my console looks like: (the arrows are my comments)

```
1 <-- input
2 <-- input
3 <-- input
4 <-- input
a <-- input (program ends after this input)
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
```

but this is what I want

```
1 <-- input
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
2 <-- input
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
3 <-- input
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
4 <-- input
00000000: 6465 6667 0a                           defg.. <-- output
a <-- input (program ends after this input)
```

(it's a simple test program in which it will print a set string if a number is inputted else it will exit)

a.c program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    const char test[7] = {0x64,0x65,0x66,0x67,'\n',0x00};
    int testInteger;
    while(scanf("%d", &testInteger)){
        printf(test);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So the `1\n2\n3\n4\a\n` is input?  Why are you showing the input interleaved with the text on the terminal?  Just show the output.

Comment: nah so I have a loop in C like this ```while(scanf("%d", &testInt)){printf(test);}``` so it receives a line of input and prints a string as output. (It's just a test example as I've got another program which will output non-string characters and I want to print them in hex). The interleaved text is what I'd expect to see in my console as I'm running it.

Comment: `0d 0a` looks horribly like Windows-y CR+LF? You may want to delete the CR with `tr`.

Comment: I used a hex to ascii converter and just put that in, my string is made up of a hex array (ik that's really wierd). fixed that now

Comment: A [mre] would be a good addition. We don't have access to your `./a.out`, how are we supposed to test this? Is the behavior reproducible with other programs? `seq` for example.

Comment: @oguzismail I've appended the C program now

Comment: If you don't have linefeeds in your data, the `read` in your `bash` or any `awk`  isn't going to work too well.

Comment: Output to a pipe is buffered. Call `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf()` or turn off buffering with `setvbuf()`.

Comment: @Barmar, This is mainly for a toy exploit, so I won't have the ability to change the binary to call fflush. Am I correct in thinking that the bash console prints this output as it receives it through stdout? Therefore isn't there a way to simply redirect this into my own program?

Comment: The bash console is irrelevant. Buffering means that the program doesn't write it.

Comment: You can use the `unbuffer` tool that's included with Expect.

Comment: But when I run the program on it's own without piping it works just as I expect, it waits for input then it prints a response

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered when it's connected to a terminal, fully buffered in other cases.

Comment: If you're an advanced enough programmer that you're designing exploits, this should be well known to you.

Comment: Did you try `tee`? Something like this `./a.out | tee | xxd`?

Comment: @accdias That won't make a difference, `a.out` still buffers it output when writing to the pipe.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: The proper way to pipe a loop is with `while stuff; do ... done | xxd`; but of course, in this case, your `while` loop was just a really slow and buggy [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: @Barmar, I'm just learning about the basics of binary exploitation, not at the stage of developing full exploits for anything complicated, so I'm not incredibly experienced in the workings of linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `stdout` is fully buffered when writing to a pipe, so `read` doesn't receive anything until the output is flushed. This won't happen until the program has written 4K bytes (almost 700 lines) or exits.

You can use [`stdbuf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html) to alter the buffering.

```
stdbuf -oL a.out | xxd
```

`-oL` switches to line buffering, so `xxd` (or any other program) will receive each line as it's printed.

Comment: The problem is that the output buffer isn't flushed until `a.out` exits. So `while read` can't read anything until the program ends. He wants to see each line as it's printed.